# Disable crash reporting dialogue Buttons

Tags: android

When an android app crash, a dialogue box come with button "ok" and "report". Is there any way to remove this "report" button or disable the dialogue programatically??

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do that.

Comment: actualy my app is kiosk app. I have all the required permissions like Administartor etc..Still no way to block this??

Comment: If you want to disable this dialog, you have to disable crashes from your app. ;)

Comment: That is handled by the Android system. I am afraid you can not disable that.

Comment: actually that is not my case. Its kiosk app I want to block this dialogue if crash occurs from another app also.

Comment: I don't think that you can do that even with kiosk mode. Probably you can if you have root access.

Comment: I have the root access.